# Placeholder Syntax in Scala Programming

Tags: scala, lambda

I came across the below placeholder syntax in scala. And could not able to under what '_' is doing in the code

```
def evenDef(n: Int): Int => Boolean = _ => n % 2 == 0
 //evenDef: (n: Int)Int => Boolean

val result = evenDef(2)
//res: Int => Boolean = $$Lambda$5397/911325@3aa9352

result(9)
//res18: Boolean = true
```

I am little confused how the above is returning 'true' for the value 9, even though its a odd number.

Can anyone help me in understand the '_' in the code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is equivalent to

```
def evenDef(n: Int): Int => Boolean = (ignored: Int) => n % 2 == 0
```

Since `ignored` is not used anywhere it can be replaced with the underscore placeholder.

Admittedly the code is a bit useless the way it stands. For any integer `n` it returns a constant function that either returns `true` for even values of `n` and `false` otherwise. The argument of the returned function does not matter at all.